# Vue - Firebase commit action scoping issue?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuex

I had this line of code that didn't work:

```
actions: {
    getFirebaseDb({commit}) {
      let rooms = []
      db.collection("rooms").get().then(function(querySnapshot){
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            let room = doc.data()
            rooms.push(room)
        })
      })
      commit('SET_ROOMS', rooms)
    }
}
```

but then I was told to move the commit up and inside the db.collection() like so:

```
actions: {
    getFirebaseDb({commit}) {
      let rooms = []
      db.collection("rooms").get().then(function(querySnapshot){
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            let room = doc.data()
            rooms.push(room)
        })
        commit('SET_ROOMS', rooms)
      })
    }
}
```

and it works. Why?

I created the rooms array outside the scope of db.collection() so it should be available to commit outside. I have no idea why this works. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the function passed as argument for the `.then()` is executed asynchronously.

This means it is not executed right away, but some time in the (hopefully near) future.

This is how asynchronous code, e.g. Promises, work. And `db.collection("rooms").get()` returns a promise.

You code runs as follows:

```js
getFirebaseDb({commit}) {
  let rooms = []                                              // this executes right away
  db.collection("rooms").get().then(function(querySnapshot){
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {                            // this executes in the future
        let room = doc.data()                                 // this executes in the future
        rooms.push(room)                                      // this executes in the future
    })                                                        // this executes in the future
  })
  commit('SET_ROOMS', rooms)                                  // this executes right away
}
```

Let's check a hopefully simpler demo that depicts that situation:

```js
let arr = [];
console.log('right away 1', arr);

setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('this will run 1 second later1', arr);
  arr.push('x');
  console.log('this will run 1 second later2', arr);
}, 1000);

console.log('right away 2', arr);
```

Notice that, despite being "first" in the code, the function passed to `setTimeout()` is executed (at least) one second later in the future. It is an asynchronous, not synchronous, code.

Comment: Wow. I just got learned. Nicely stated. Thanks for putting those comments on the side of the code. That helped a lot. Thanks!